# Single local notification in didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote

Using the estimote beacons, I get multiple local notifications fired from `didEnterRegion`. I only range & monitor 1 region under which all my beacons reside.

I am trying to restrict this functionality so that users only get notified once whilst in the region. I would think this is out-of-the-box functionality since there's a corresponding `didExitRegion` event, so in essence you only get 1 notification whilst inside the region.

I don't see this behaviour though. Event `didEnterRegion` fires multiple times while I am physically inside the region. So I implemented a counter that's initially set to 0 and increments by 1 every time I'm inside `didEnterRegion`. I only allow the local notification to fire when the counter < 1.

But this has left me wondering; how will this work when the app is not running? Also, by doing it this way (i.e. not resetting the counter back to 0 via `didExitRegion`) do I only notify the user just once throughout the presence of the app on his phone, regardless the times he will physically enter / exit the region (while the app is installed and not running)? I want to inform him just once whilst in the region, and not just once in general.

I'm clearly confused with this, so would love to hear any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not monitoring the same beacon multiple times, by inspecting the `monitoredRegions` property of your `ESTBeaconManager`/`CLLocationManager`.

Comment: when you say "inspecting"? so does this mean that I don't need to keep counters etc?

Comment: ah.. just seen this https://forums.estimote.com/t/methods-didenterregion-called-multiple-times/3074

Comment: The simplest way to inspect it would be to print it out to the console I guess (: Then you can see if you're monitoring the same beacon more than once, under different identifiers.

Comment: this can't be the case since I explicitly stop monitoring & ranging any active regions at the start of my execution, ahead of any re-monitoring & re-ranging, i.e. for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions { locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region as! CLBeaconRegion)} locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)